# jQuery post resulting data

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a jQuery drag and drop based panel working perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/pzRgT/

It stores multiple draggable elements over multiple lists. I'm unsure how I would store the order and send that to my server such that I can store the data and load it back later to re-create the order.

How can I store the elements and their order over multiple boxes such that I can "save" and "load" from ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `id` attributes to the `<ul>`s to identify the groups, `id` attributes to the `<li>`s to identify them. Then spin through the `<ul>`s when you want to save it and convert the current state to a JavaScript object; once you have that object you can send it back to the server as JSON, unpack it on the server, and store it in your database.

Something like this:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var groups = { };
    $('.sort').each(function() {
        var a = [ ];
        $(this).find('li').each(function() {
            a.push(this.id);
        });
        groups[this.id] = a;
    });
    // Send groups back to the server using $.ajax()
});
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FMKmj/

Comment: Looks great thx, do you have an example of the 
// Send groups back to the server using $.ajax() function?

Comment: @Webby: [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) takes an object as its `data` parameter so `$.ajax({url: '...', data: groups, ...})`.